# multiprocessing shared_memory - no such file

Tags: python, subprocess, shared-memory

I am trying to access a `shared_memory` from a `subprocess` but I am having errors like:

```
shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=line.decode('utf-8'), create=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/shared_memory.py", line 100, in __init__
    self._fd = _posixshmem.shm_open(
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/psm_a5c1de7f'
```

Take the sample code for reference:

in `mysubprocess.py`

```
from multiprocessing import shared_memory


s = "some string"
shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=len(s))
buffer = shm.buf
buffer[:] = bytes(s, 'utf-8')
print(shm.name)
```

in `test.py`

```
import subprocess
from multiprocessing import shared_memory


proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'mysubprocess.py'],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)


for line in proc.stdout.readlines():
    line = line.strip()
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=line.decode('utf-8'), create=False)
    buffer = shm.buf
    print(bytes(buffer))
```

I am using Windows 10, but running it on docker ubuntu 20.04 with python 3.8.5

Comment: `shared_memory` was designed to work with `multiprocessing.Process` and `multiprocessing.Pool`, not `subprocess.Popen`. It's also unclear why you are giving  different names to each shared_memory block. Please provide a runnable [mre].

Comment: The code sample run as it is, with the error I am questioning about. The name of the memory block is different since my real scenario does different things. Anyways, thats not related to my question. So are you saying there is no way to make it work with subprocess?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it will work with `subprocess` or not. Regardless, the problem with giving each one a different name is that other processes will need to know at lease one of them in order to access it. You aren't providing the name of any of the existing ones when trying to access them in the other process running `mysubprocess.py`.

Comment: The name is being printed in stdout. The main process reads the name from the pipe, and suppose to load that shared memory given the name.  But if it wont work for subprocess, then it wont work. Regardless, the name not being provided is not the issue

Comment: The code in your question doesn't show doing that, which is what I meant about you not providing a [mre].